# What happened to the reputation from this unupvote?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, reputation-history

Yesterday there was an unupvote on [one of my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317495/scoring-and-ranking-specificity-rules/9317528#9317528). There was a -10 in this record when I first noticed I'd lost 10 rep.

But when I look at [my reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=reputation) today, that reputation value is no longer there:

[image]

Why is it blank now? What's happened to that 0.007% of my precious reputation? Was it returned to me... or is it gone forever? ☹

Comment: Also: the post was neither edited nor voted on yesterday, but I guess somebody slipped in a ninja edit, removed their vote, then undid their edit to destroy the revision. In any case, that's not relevant here.

Comment: Merged with the upvote and nullified, cancelled out, ex-voted?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I guess I shouldn't have cropped out the post titles - all the upvotes on this day were for different posts. *Edit:* just uploaded a screenshot with the titles partially uncropped.

Comment: I guessed that already as the posts have not been merged. :-)

Comment: If you're able to ship a large quantity of [Laksa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laksa) to a discrete location that I specify, we can negotiate the return of that rep.

Comment: The [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9317495/timeline) for the question only records one upvote, way back in February. Doesn't mean anything, just showing I am trying to investigate this mysterious missing upvote that has been unupvoted.

Comment: I've seen weird stuff like this happen before. It usually involves an unupvote followed by a rep-recalc triggered either manually or by deletion/undeletion of a post. This combined with the repcap "moves" the rep points to another post (possibly on a different day). But the total rep is always still correct.

Comment: @Mysticial: And your answer to my last question is...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I dunno. If I had to guess, it didn't change at all since you were probably capped on the day the upvote was cast.

Comment: interesting. Looks like a drop of milk on your monitor, did you try wiping it?

Comment: [Here's another one of those unexplained cases I've seen.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hv2O0.png) It's not the same situation here, but weird nonetheless. 5 events at 20:07.

Comment: @Tim Post: I would, gladly. My poor equine taste buds can't stand laksa.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised you're so confused at this. The rules of voting are that an upvote and unupvote that appear *on the same day* get rolled up and hidden from view. So the fact that it's appearing at all means the original upvote appeared on another day. Looking at the answer itself, it's only been edited once on the day it was posted, which means the upvote would have to have occurred on February 16 in order for that vote to be removable.

> [image: Your reputation history from Feb 16]

Presto! An upvote with no rep gain!

Comment: Cool, so the upvote that was undone had been capped. That's one mystery solved! It doesn't explain why the -10 was there when I first saw it and I lost 10 rep at that very moment though (not that I care if I got it back later)...

Comment: Maybe it confused the system? Have you *still* lost the 10 reputation or did it correct it? I assume it's just the system automatically applying a -10 for an unupvote then checking later to see if it was actually a +10.

Comment: I have no idea what happened to that 10 reputation either. If the system was confused, I'm equally so.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Here's the deal. When an upvote that gives rep is removed later, it will appear as giving no rep after a recalc. Those "missing points" are moved to another vote on the same day. I've seen this happen many times.

Comment: Ah, right. This particular vote was probably not capped, so removing the upvote moved you back down to 190 as far as the cap was concerned, so you were only shown a -10 until the system recalculated that day to account for the change, at which point that vote became the capped one.